# "Put a knife to/at/on throat" - which one is preferred?

Tags: prepositions, indian-english

I see three different versions on Indian media. The context is threatening someone to do some work forcefully.

> Put a knife *on* my throat 
>  Put a knife *at* my throat 
>  Put a knife *to* my throat

I feel 'on' should be the choice. Kindly enlighten me.

Okay! Are those all three possible?

Comment: If someone said "Someone put a knife on my throat!" I would picture their assailant trying to gently place a knife upon their throat (which would be an absolute bitch to balance). Having a knife "to" one's throat is the most common one I hear, but it would be just as valid to use "at".

Comment: @JohnC - On top of something else? I cringe when we limit the meanings prepositions as we try to explain them to learners; they are too flexible for such generalizations. (Consider, for example, _"Hang the picture on that wall. Her house is on the beach. He needed stitches on his foot. She cut her finger on a nail and got blood on her dress."_) Moreover, Google finds dozens of hits for [knife on his throat](https://www.google.com/?q=%22knife+on+his+throat%22), many from books, court records, and official criminal reports. The preposition "to" may be more common or idiomatic, but "on" is okay.

Comment: @J.R. Okay, fair enough. I still don't like it. :-)

Comment: @JohnC - It's not my favorite, either; my preferences would probably be _put a knife **to**_ or _hold a knife **at**_. But those preferences are merely rooted in what seems most idiomatic to my ear, not in some limitation of the word _on_. (If my wife told me a thief put a knife on her throat, I wouldn't picture him trying to gently achieve a delicate balance.)

Comment: @J.R. Your last point is a good one. I guess I'm just stubborn in my application of prepositions. :)

Comment: @JohnC - The longer I've been on ELL, the more I've marveled at the flexibility of prepositions. No wonder we get so many questions about them! I gave a few examples earlier, but I tried to steer clear of the more figurative or idiomatic uses of _on_ (like _on board, on target, on fire, on the money, on a roll, on the phone, on drugs, on television, on the radio, on a diet, on my way, on call, on purpose, on Christmas Eve_, or _On the Waterfront_). P.S. Wanna go grab a bite to eat? Lunch is on me.

Answer (score 4):

When an assailant puts a knife to your throat you have a knife at your throat.

Comment: When an assailant puts a knife on my throat, I'll let him use any preposition he wants.

Comment: When an assailant puts the knife on your throat, do everything you can to prevent them from putting it into your throat.

Comment: Does it answer my question?

Comment: Yes it does.  **Put...to** is used in contexts of wielding an implement or weapon.